# Return promises in order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm facing an issue to return promises using [**$q#all**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) method.

I want to make promises dependent on each other, *i.e.*:

If I set `obj1, obj2 and obj3` I want to get them in the same **order**.

How can I achieve this?

**`Factory:`**

```
mainFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

function mainFactory($http, $q) {
  var mainFactory = {
    getPromises: getPromises
  };

  return mainFactory;

  function getPromises(id) {
    promises = {
      'obj1': $http.get('http1'),
      'obj2': $http.get('http2'),
      'obj3': $http.get('http3'),
      'obj4': $http.get('http4', { params: { 'id': id } }),
      'obj5': $http.get('http5'),
      'obj6': $http.get('http6', { params: { 'id': id } })
    };

    return $q.all(promises);
  }
}
```

**`Controller:`**

```
MainCtrl.$inject = ['mainFactory'];

function MainCtrl(mainFactory) {
  var vm = this;
  mainFactory.getPromises(id)
    .then(getResponse)
    .catch(getError);

  function getResponse(response) {
    var keys = Object.keys(response), i = keys.length;
    while (i--) {
      var key = keys[i];
      console.log(key); // I want all the keys in order, i.e. => obj1, obj2.. and so on
      var value = response[key].data;
      switch(key) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }

  function getError(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I tried this way also:

```
var promises = {};
return $http.get('/admin/http1.json').then(function (value) {
    promises['obj1'] = value;
  })
.then(function (result) {
    return $http.get('/admin/http2.json').then(function (value) {
    promises['obj2'] = value;
  });
}).then(function (result) {
    return $http.get('/admin/http3.json').then(function (value) {
    promises['obj3'] = value;
  });
});     
return $q.all(promises);
```

Comment: i'm not good with promises, sorry, but an alternative is to use http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.eachOfSeries

Comment: Object keys are inherently *unordered*. Use an array instead.

Comment: Check out this article on $q.serial(). I think it would be exactly what you're looking for. http://www.codeducky.org/q-serial/

Comment: It is not clear from the code why the promises are 'dependent on each other'. This may affect the way how they should be processed.

Comment: I got it working using an `array` instead of `object`. Thanks @JaredSmith.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2**

Mistake, I just copied you code above without realizing it was an object. LOL.

```
promises = [
  $http.get('http1'),
  $http.get('http2'),
  $http.get('http3'),
  $http.get('http4', { params: { 'id': id } }),
  $http.get('http5'),
  $http.get('http6', { params: { 'id': id } })
]
```

**Edit 1**

Sorry I didn't notice the comments [Jared Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3757232/jared-smith) is correct.

> Object keys are inherently unordered. Use an array instead.

**Edit 0**

Object keys wont be ordered. Use array on declaring your promises.

```
promises = [
  $http.get('http1'),
  $http.get('http2'),
  $http.get('http3'),
  $http.get('http4', { params: { 'id': id } }),
  $http.get('http5'),
  $http.get('http6', { params: { 'id': id } })
]

$q.all(promises)
  .then(functions(resolves){
      // resolves here is an array
  }).catch(function(err){ 
      // throw err 
  });
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`. Not sure if that was supposed to be an object... but it's definitely not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Using `$q.all` will resolve each promise **in no particular order**. If you want them to execute after each promise has been resolve, use **promise chaining**.

```
function getPromises(id) {
  var getObjA = function () {
    return $http.get('http1');
  };

  var getObjB = function () {
    return $http.get('http2');
  };

  var getObjC = function () {
    return $http.get('http3');
  };

  var getObjD = function () {
    return $http.get('http4', { params: { 'id': id } });
  };

  var getObjE = function () {
    return $http.get('http5');
  };

  var getObjF = function () {
    return $http.get('http5', { params: { 'id': id } });
  };

  return getObjA()
    .then(getObjB)
    .then(getObjC)
    .then(getObjD)
    .then(getObjE)
    .then(getObjF);
}
```

Edit: as an additional info, you can catch any error in any of those promise by placing a catch statement here

```
getPromises("id")
   .then(<success callback here>)
   .catch(<error callback that will catch error on any of the promises>);
```

Meaning, once a promise fails, all the succeeding promises below wouldn't be executed and will be caught by your catch statement